# If for every nonzero element $a$ of $R$ we have $aR=R$..

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Problem is "Let $R$ be a commutative ring with more than one element. prove that If for every nonzero element $a$ of $R$ we have $aR=R$, then $R$ is a field." 
If unity exists in $R$, it is trival. But i have no idea to prove it.

Comment: Hint $a\in R$ should help

Comment: a∈aR means r exists in R such that ar=a. then..

Comment: hint : $1 \in aR$ should help

Comment: For each $a\in R$ there is an identity $e_a$ such that $e_aa=ae_a=a$. One must show that $e_a=e_b$ for every $a,b\in R$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet The point is that you must show that $1$ exists in $R$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet The statement $1\in aR$ presupposes the existence of $1$...

Comment: Sorry I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: Indeed you get $ar=a$ for some $r$. Also commutativity gives $ra=a$. Then from the condition, if $c\in R$ there is a $b\in R$ with $ab=c$.. Then $cr=abr=bar=ba=ab=c$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $R$ has more than one element, it has a nonzero element. Let $a\in R$, $a\neq 0$. Then $a\in aR$. Let $e\in R$ such that $ae=ea=a$.

Let $r\in R$. There is some $s\in R$ such that $as=r$. Now,
$$re=er=eas=as=r$$
so $e=1$ in $R$.

Comment: oh very thank you. I got it

Answer (score 1):

Take any element $a\in R$. Then $aR=R$ which means that $a\in aR$, so there exists some $e\in R$ such that $ae=ea=a$.

Now take any $b\in R$. Since $b\in aR$, there exists some $b'$ such that $b=ab'$ which means that $$b=ab'\\
b=(ea)b'\\
b=e(ab')\\
b=eb$$

so $b=eb=be$ for all $b\in R$, in other words, $e=1$.

Comment: Sir why unity $1\in R$ implies $R$ is field? Please reply